# Protractor not able to click on a repeater row

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am facing a strange behavior when testing an Angular JS application with protractor.
Considering this HTML structure , I would like to click on the inner div which is a filter.

```
 <div ng-hide="term.selected" ng-click="selectFilter('target',term.value)"     class="listItem">
                <div>
                    <label class="ng-binding">ZECPFICO00</label>
                    <span class="listItemNum ng-binding">157</span>
                </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my locator :

```
element(by.repeater('term in facets.target | filter:ecSearchText').row(1)).click ();
```

When executing this code my webdriver cursor goes to the filter in the web page but and tries to click on the filter however the click does not work and therefore the filter is not applied.

Comment: On which browser are you running your tests ? :)

Answer (score 4):

1 - You don't need to specify the filters when using by.repeater it is optional

2 - Sirk is almost there, you need to continue chaining your promises, below an example of clicking on a div, you can use any by method here..

```
var elements = element.all(by.repeater('term in facets.target'));
elements.first().then(function (term) {
    term.findElement(by.css('div')).then(function (div) {
            div.click();
        });
});
```

3- You could also do it this way:

```
element.all(by.repeater('term in facets.target')).get(0).click();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i know .first() earlier but i wanted to click on the 3rd element. So this code worked. element.all(by.repeater('term in facets.target')).get(2).click();

Answer (score 0):

hmm I've never seen or used a locator that way where you have .row(1), but I am a noob so that just might be my own ignorance, however you could try something like the following:

```
element(by.repeater('term in facets.target | filter:ecSearchText')).then(function(rows){
   rows[0].click();
});
```

That should click on the first row of the repeater. 'rows' would contain all the rows as an array.

Comment: I have also tried it that way it did not work! btw you can use the row function with the repeater, in fact i can see web driver trying to click on the web element but it did not work!

Comment: Ah ok fair enough i've just never seen it like so thought id try and contribute. does the test fail on the click event or does it try to carry on?, does it work with xpath? obviously you don't want to permanently use xpath but i find its a useful tool to find out if you are focusing on the correct element

Comment: oh its also worth noting, however i dont know if this will affect you, but, when locating an element protractor will always default to the center of the element unless an offset is specified, so if the center of your element is not clickable then the mouse will go there however it wont be able to click it, this might effect you if only the text on teh row is clickable and not the whole row itself

Comment: the test carry on but fails as the filter is not applied and my test asserts that results have been filtered.I can't use xpath in this particular test as my page structure changes so xpath changes depending on data.

Comment: in my case the whole span is clickable but thanks for the info interesting!!

Comment: Ok I'm pretty much stumped then sorry mate, the only other last thing you could possibly try, because i had a similar issue though my element was static and never changing really, is to be even more specific so 
`ptor.findElement(protractor.By.repeater('term in facets.targe | filter:ecSearchText').row(1)).findElement(protractor.By.tagName('span')).click();`
i had to do this where the element was made up of multiple tags so that it got specific one that was clickable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49244/discussion-between-ziwdigforbugs-and-sirk)

Comment: for info when using your suggestion i got angular not defined error

Comment: that suggests that protractor cant find angular then, maybe go through your angular implementation and make sure its set up properly?? not sure try a search for the error you're getting i've seen a few posts with that message in the past but never had it myself, sorry mate.